# iOS build disappears from iTunes Connect

Tags: xcode, build, app-store-connect, testflight

I'm using Xcode 8.3.3 to upload an App on itunes connect. Xcode shows me that the uploading is successful. In Activity tab of iTunesConnect I see that my build is appears and it's marked as "processing...". But after a few minutes this build disappears and I cannot find it anywhere. I tried to upload it, but it says the build is already uploaded to iTunesConnect. So when I tried to upload build with increased version it says OK, but I still cannot see the build in iTunesConnect. There isn't a way for know error code of the processing? I have no information.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your email ( registered with itunes), check spam folder. If build is removed that means there were errors while processing.

Comment: I checked in spam folder but there isn't neither.

Comment: contact apple support team via itunesconnect

Answer (score 0):

Check your mail. Your build might get rejected so Apple sent rejection reason to mail. You might have received Invalid swift support error in mail

Comment: I have not received any mail from Apple and I don't understand the problem.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to add your Email in User and Role Section in iTunes.
When you are uploading your application, if the process of uploading is successfull, you need to wait if your app did not miss anything specially in info.Plist.
after a few mintues, you will receive an Email regarding the iOS application you uploaded.

if it says: 
**The following build has completed processing:

Platform: iOS

App Name: ......

Build Number:....

Version Number: .......

App SKU: ......

App Apple ID: .......

You can now use this build for TestFlight testing or submit it to the App Store.**

This means the process is sucessfull.
 But you may face some issues which will be emailed to you in a few time, and it causes that your app will be disappeared in iTunes Page. You are not able to build this version again unless you delete the archive, So go and increase the build version in XCode and fix the error base on the Email you receieved.